# Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory' to required type 'jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory'

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jakarta-migration

I'm using Spring(5.3.27) JMS and ActiveMQ(5.16.1) to send a message. Now, I am migrating my project to Spring 6.0.0 and getting the error while running integration tests:
***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory' to required type 'jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found***

Below is the configuration for same:

```
<bean id="messagingConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${messaging.broker.url}" />
    <property name="transportListener" ref="activeMQState"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${messaging.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${messaging.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
  init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" >
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${messaging.pool.maxConnections}" />
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="${messaging.pool.maxActiveSessionsPerConnection}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="messagingConnectionFactory" />
</bean> 

<bean id="messagingTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsPooledConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

activemq-client extends ConnectionFactory which is part of jakarta.jms-api-2.0.3 but package name is javax.jms
Can someone please tell me what dependencies should I include/exclude to make it compatible with Spring 6?

I tried updating the active-client and other ActiveMQ dependencies to 5.18.1 (latest versions)but it's failing with Spring 6.0.0 but working with Spring 5.3.27

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveMQ 5.18.1 release did provide a Jakarta compatible messaging client but the bulk of the broker remains based on the javax.jms namespaced JMS API and as such things like the connection pool provided by the ActiveMQ broker will not work in Spring 6.  There is another option which is to use the [Pooled JMS](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) connection pooling library instead which provides releases for both Jakarta messaging and the legacy javax.jms API.

The ActiveMQ 5.x broker should have a full Jakarta based release at some point in the near future but no date is currently set.

Comment: FYI-- A SNAPSHOT build off the PR would work. Unit tests are passing for activemq-pool and activemq-jms-pool - ref: https://github.com/apache/activemq/pull/996.  The current TODOs are all mostly related to http service and web layer things